# How to read mifare id from card using windows phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, mifare, apdu

I'm trying to get the mifare id from a smartcard using a windows phone 8.1 device (lumia 735 and 830) and the new Windows.Devices.SmartCards namespace libraries (using the javacard api).

I've successfully managed to do most things (select applets, read datastores and authenticate), but cannot get a sensible response from the well documented APDU for reading the mifare id:

0xFF 0xCA 0x00 0x00 0x00

I get a 0x6700 response - which the javacard framework reports as SW_WRONG_LENGTH.

My colleague is doing the same with Android, and has no problem using the same card. I've also tried many variations of the APDU e.g. 0xFF 0xCA and 0xFF 0xCA 0x00 etc etc.

Does anyone have any experience with doing this on WP8.1?

Comment: I am just curious - does WP8.1 support non-NDEF tags? I was trying to build some NFC app but was unable to do it as WP8 supported only NDEF tags. Thanks in advance, I have upvoted you!

Comment: It does, but only on phones which have the new PN547 chipset (lumia 830 and 735). This is well documented on the web.

Comment: Yes, I have found it on the internet after your reading question :) I hoped it depended on availability of an UMDF driver, not a special chipset.